# Is there a fully functional NSGA-II implementation?

Tags: data-mining

I am working on multi-objective association rule mining. For this, I want to use NGSA II algorithm. Is there any fully functional NSGA-II implementation in python or MATLAB that takes standard dataset as input?

Comment: Have you had a look at [DEAP](https://github.com/DEAP/deap)?